# Support for Banno Conversations through the API

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

Is there a away to start a conversation through the API?  I see other calls for messages but nothing to post.  We have a large list of customers we want to message and don't want to do it manually.  Any assistance would be great.

This isn't applicable since I don't have an API call to try.

Answer (score 0):

Banno Conversations is not available as part of the Banno Digital Toolkit's open API.